# Hypothesis testing on a moving-average model on unevenly-spaced time series

Tags: hypothesis-testing, moving-average, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have some irregular time series $X$, where $X_t$ are identically distributed, and bounded between 0 and 1. I perform a moving average $Y_t = \sum_{t'} \frac{w(t-t')}{\sum_k w(t-k)}X_{t'}$. The coefficient $w(t-t')$ is defined below.

$ w(t -t') \begin{cases} 1 \quad t-t' \leq a\\ \frac{a^2}{(t-t')^2} \quad a < t-t' \leq b\\ 0 \quad b< t-t'\end{cases}$

When I do the average $\overline{Y}$ of a random sample of $Y_t$, this average seems to tend to a Gaussian distribution. And I wonder whether an equivalent of the Central Limit Theorem could apply in this setting. This would allow me to test whether the average $\overline{Y}$ of a given sample would be statistically larger than the average $\mu$ of $Y$ on the entire time series.

Let's assume that I know the average $\mu$ and the variance $\sigma ^2$ of the entire time series, and that I can analytically compute the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ where $\sigma_{t,t'}^2$ is the covariance of $Y_t$ and $Y_{t'}$.

I have three questions:

- Can the moving-average $Y_t$ be considered as stationary? The specification of the moving average is constant for any $t$, but the observations are not evenly spaced, the coefficients $w(t-t')$ depend on $t$.
- Are the variables $Y_t$ weakly dependent from each other, as the coefficient $w(t - t')$ is 0 when $t-t'$ exceeds a certain value $b$?
- Is there a equivalent of the Central Limit Theorem that could apply here on the average $\overline{Y}$ of a sample of $Y$?